# How can I properly configure web server (or wss?) (or ssl?) for phabricator notifications?

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2, websocket, phabricator

Please let me know if I'm asking this question badly, but here is my situation. I'm trying to set up a phabricator server on AWS EC2 for my organization. The main phabricator server is fine, but I'm struggling to get the notification (aphlict) server working.

- I can start the server successfully with `phabricator/.bin/aphlict start` (or at least `phabricator/.bin/aphlict status` gives `Aphlict (1461) is running.`)
- Though strangely, `phabricator/.bin/aphlict debug` gives `Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line` and an uncaught exception of `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/log/aphlict.log'`
- My console in firefox gives `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://phabricator.<redacted>.com:22280/.`
- My notification server configuration page on phabricator shows `[cURL/7] (https://phabricator.<redacted>.com:22280/) <CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT>` The cURL library raised an error while making a request. You may be able to find more information about this error (error code: 7) on the cURL site: [http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLECOULDNTCONNECT`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLECOULDNTCONNECT%60)

I am desperately trying to follow the instructions from https://phabricator.tbmh.org/book/phabricator/article/notifications/ but I really don't understand web sockets, HTTPS, TCP, or SSL well enough. I am serving my phabricator site over HTTPS, and am pretty sure I need to do some version of this:

> If you serve Phabricator over HTTPS, you must also serve websockets over HTTPS. Browsers will refuse to connect to ws:// websockets from HTTPS pages.
>
> If a client connects to Phabricator over HTTPS, Phabricator will automatically select an appropriate HTTPS service from notification.servers and instruct the browser to open a websocket connection with wss://.
>
> The simplest way to do this is configure Aphlict with an SSL key and certificate and let it terminate SSL directly.

But unfortunately I can't figure out exactly what I should change to make it all work.

Here is my `sudo ./bin/config get notification.servers`:

```
{
  "config": [
    {
      "key": "notification.servers",
      "source": "local",
      "value": [
        {
          "type": "client",
          "host": "phabricator.<redacted>.com",
          "port": 22280,
          "protocol": "https"
        },
        {
          "type": "admin",
          "host": "127.0.0.1",
          "port": 22281,
          "protocol": "http"
        }
      ],
      "status": "set",
      "errorInfo": null
    },
    {
      "key": "notification.servers",
      "source": "database",
      "value": null,
      "status": "unset",
      "errorInfo": null
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is my `phabricator/conf/aphlict/aphlict.default.json`:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "type": "client",
      "port": 22280,
      "listen": "0.0.0.0",
      "ssl.key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/fullchain.pem",
      "ssl.cert": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/privkey.pem",
      "ssl.chain": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/chain.pem"
    },
    {
      "type": "admin",
      "port": 22281,
      "listen": "127.0.0.1",
      "ssl.key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/fullchain.pem",
      "ssl.cert": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/privkey.pem",
      "ssl.chain": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/chain.pem"
    }
  ],
  "logs": [
    {
      "path": "/var/log/aphlict.log"
    }
  ],
  "pidfile": "/var/tmp/aphlict/pid/aphlict.pid"
}
```

I've also added TCP inbound `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0` rules on ports 22281 and 22280 in AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally get the solution. In the end I was just using the wrong permutation of `.pem` files...it needed to be this:

```
      "ssl.key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/privkey.pem",
      "ssl.cert": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/cert.pem",
      "ssl.chain": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/phabricator.<redacted>.com/fullchain.pem"
```